# What's the difference between まだ and いまだ（に）?

Tags: usage, words, nuances

My intuition *wants* to believe that `いまだに` is more formal, but all the examples I've seen do not indicate that.  Are they freely interchangeable?  Can't say I've ever heard `いまだに` in spoken context (or ever really seen it often in written context either).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Originally there was only imada. It is a compound of the noun ima (今) and the stem of the particle [dani](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AB&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=1&pagenum=1&index=11571400), da. It has two primary meanings: 1) not yet 2) still. When used in the positive sense 2), it emphasizes a continuation from the past.

mada is a contraction from imada. It is much more colloquial than the former. While they both share these two meanings, mada has evolved a number of other finer [senses](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&stype=1&dtype=0&dname=0ss&p=%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0). As a result, imada is now most associated and used for its negative sense "not yet".

Note that 未 is always given the reading "imada... -zu" in 漢文 texts and means "not yet", never "still". This is origin of words such as 未来 (未だ来ず imada ko-zu, that which has not yet come --> the future).

Comment: What are your sources for the part about it being a compound of 今 + だに.  [大辞泉 seems to directly contradict this (specifically, "「今だに」と書くのは誤り。").](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0%E3%81%AB&dtype=0&dname=0na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=01176800)

Comment: @istrasci: That is just saying that 今だに is wrong in *current* practice. Generally you should write as just Hiragana.

Comment: @JesseGood: What part of `「今だに」と書くのは誤り` indicates "current practice"?  To me, that says it's incorrect to write it that way at all times.  If it really stemmed from `今+だに`, I don't think it would say that it's incorrect to write that way; it would probably say something like "generally you should write it as Hiragana".

Comment: According to [Daijisen](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/detail?p=%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0&stype=1&dtype=0), it is not so conclusive that the origin of だ in いまだ is the first part of だに.

Comment: 日本国語大辞典 (2版): 名詞「今」に、助詞「だに」の語根と同じ「だ」が付いたもの